# Ultra 20 won't boot if second hard drive added

Tags: sun, bios

I have an aged Ultra 20 (AMD) running Solaris 10 that boots fine as long as another hard drive has not been added to the bus; with the second drive added, I can't even get to BIOS settings, instead seeing "Sun Microsystems" logo, never getting any further. If secondary drive is formatted or unformatted, I have same results.

Any suggestions how to address this? I don't have a lot of experience with BIOS and/or hardware.

Cheers, Doug

Comment: Have you tried using the drive you're adding, as the first and only drive?  If it then boots, what if you put the original drive as second drive?  Does it boot then?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused because of drives formatted/partitioned on a Mac. Once they had been wiped and partitioned with MBR and formatted as "free space", my box was able to boot again, and then they were formatted within Solaris. Still, very odd I couldn't even get to the BIOS menu. Oh well